# Start tomcat7 in debug mode when running as a service

Tags: 12.04, tomcat, tomcat7

Im running tomcat7 as a service (installed as a package) in ubuntu 12.04. I just need to start it in debug mode.in a previous post they have asked to put the debugging options in /etc/tomcat7/tomcat7.conf. But i cannot find the tomcat7.conf in /etc/tomcat7 folder.

In /usr/share/tomcat7 i have

```
bin defaults.md5sum defaults.template lib
```

In /var/lib/tomcat7/conf i have

```
Catalina catalina.properties context.xml logging.properties policy.d server.xml tomcat-users.xml web.xml
```

same files and folders are available in /etc/tomcat7 as well.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I´m using Ubuntu 14.04 server, and the files needed to run Tomcat7 in debug mode are under **/usr/share/tomcat/bin**.
There you can find **startup.sh** and **catalina.sh**. Those two are usually the only files you need to modify to start the server in debug mode.
I hope it helps.
Regards.